# Pipelining multiple strings into a single cli application

Tags: command-line

My application, which is written in C, uses `gets()` to retrieve user input. Lets assume it asks for a name and a password. Currently, I use

```
printf "thisIsMyUsername" | ./myapplication
```

to tell the application what the user name is. It skips requesting the password and terminates.

I want to be able to input both, user and password, using the `printf` command. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you expect an <kbd>Enter</kbd> after both username and password:

```
printf "username\npassword\n" | ./yourapplication
```

Just print a newline after each :)